# Get data from custom html dialog

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have not used googlescript much so this is hopefully a easy question. However I was unable to find an answer in my search.

I want to have a script that add a new button to my google sheet that opens a dialogue box with checkboxes and somehow return which boxes got ticked.

Edit: The goal is to make a message box appear, listing the names of the other sheets with a checkbox and return a list with the selected names.

Right now the value logged in createGraph(agents) is NULL, so it seems something in the HTML script is incorrect.

Here is my updated Script (edit: cut out unnecessary parts):

```
function openMsgBox() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var pages = ss.getSheets();
  var names = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++){
    var name = pages[i].getName();
    if(name != 'Template'){
     names.push(name); 
    }
  }

  if(names.length == 0){
    Browser.msgBox('Error', 'no pages exist', Browser.Buttons.OK);
    return;
  }

  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('MyHTMLFile');
  template.data = names;
  var html = template.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME).setWidth(400).setHeight(20*names.length + 100);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'title');
} 

function createGraph(agents) {
  Logger.log(agents);
}
```

And this is the updated HTML dialog box:

```
<div id="container">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Select the users you want to add</legend>
    <div id="agentList">
      <?for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
      <b> <input type="checkbox" id="agent<?=i?>" value=<?=data[i]?> /> <?=data[i]?><br /></b>
      <? } ?>
      <br />
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="OK" onClick="createGraph()" />
  </fieldset>
</div>

<script>
// Pass input to server-side createGraph()
function createGraph() {
  var agents;
  var nrOfAgents = $("#agentList > div").length;
  for(var i = 0; i < nrOfAgents; i++){
    if($('agent'+i).is(":checked")){
      agents.push($('agent'+i).value);
    }
  }

  google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(
           // input delivered, close dialog
           function() {
             google.script.host.close();
           })
           .withFailureHandler(
           function() {
             var div = $('<div id="error" class="error">' + msg + '</div>');
             $(element).after($("#container"));
           })
            .createGraph(agents);
}

</script>
```

If you have any clue how this can be accomplished feel free to enlighten me, also if you see anything else that is off with the script please point it out. As I said I'm new to googlescript and usually don't type in javascript either.

Comment: You need to use `google.script.run.myServerFunctionNameHere()` to run a function in a `.gs` script file.  To get a return back, you need to use the `.withSuccessHandler(clientFunctionNameToHandleReturn)`  [Apps Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

Comment: Thank you, I no longer have any errors in my code (that the compiler find). However I still do something wrong when trying to get the output, "createGraph(agents)" logs the parameter as NULL

I updated the first post with more info and the updated files if you feel like taking a look at them =)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I can see what you are trying to do, but you are still doing a few things wrong. Let me try to tighten up your code. I am placing comments in the code to try and explain.

This what your dialog box should look like:

```
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Select the users you want to add</legend>
    <div id="agentList">
      <?for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
      <b> <input type="checkbox" id="agent<?=i?>" value=<?=data[i]?> /> <?=data[i]?><br /></b>
      <? } ?>
      <br />
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="OK" />
  </fieldset>
</div>

<script>
//since you are using jquery i went ahead and used it
//in google scripts (as far as i know) you can't use the onclick property inside html. 
//so you have to use jquery's $().click() syntax.
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').click(function() {
    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(function(response) {
        //whatever you want to do with the response
        google.script.host.close();
      })
      .withFailureHandler(function(error) {
        var div = $('<div id="error" class="error">' + error + '</div>');
        $(element).after($("#container"));
      })
      .createGraph($('#agentsList').val());
  });
});
</script>
```

Your createGraph function should go in your server side code (whatever .gs file is called)

Hopefully this helps you out a little bit. Where can I clarify anything?

Comment: Thanks, you put me on the right track. I have now made some updates but I still have some issues with retrieving the data.

I will update the original question to make it clearer